# reuse javascript codes(reduce the Duplicate codes)

Tags: extjs, code-reuse, extend

When I make some components in my web page,I found there a so many duplicate codes,for example,in my page I want to make two charts.

THe biggest difference of them is the data store and the title,however they have many same attributes.

I do this by define a new instance of Ext.chart:

```
var chart1=new Ext.chart.LineChart{config1};

var chart2=new Ext.chart.LineChart{config2};
```

There are so many same contents in the config1 and config2,is there any ideas to avoid this?

BTW,I have thought the extend mechanism in ext,however I can not get more details about how to use it only from the ext3.2 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend config

```
var config = {
    // do you shared config here
}

// and apply any different/extending configs here
var config1 = Ext.apply(config, { title: "Title of config 1" }
var config2 = Ext.apply(config, { title: "Title of config 2" }

var chart1 = new Ext.chart.LineChart(config1);
var chart2 = new Ext.chart.LineChart(config2);
```

And if you want it even shorter:

```
var chart1 = new Ext.chart.LineChart(Ext.apply(config, {
    title: "Title of config 1"
});
var chart2 = new Ext.chart.LineChart(Ext.apply(config, {
    title: "Title of config 2"
});
```

**Edit:** With Ext.extend:

```
Ext.chart.LineChart = Ext.extend(Ext.chart.LineChart, {
    // put your shared config in here
});

var chart1 = new Ext.chart.LineChart({
    title: "Title of chart 1", 
    store: new Ext.data.Store({ ... });
});
var chart2 = new Ext.chart.LineChart({
    title: "Title of chart 2", 
    store: new Ext.data.Store({ ... });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good manner. ALso I want to know if this can be be implemented by the extend mechanism ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can already put all of the default configs inside the LineChart already and then only overwrite the changed ones